# InsertCell not working in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, html, datatable

```
var table = document.getElementById("WrksheetTable");
for(i=0;i<arrworksheets.length;i++){
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    tr.id = "tr" + i;
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    td.id = "td" + i;
    var wrksheetcheckbox = document.createElement("input");
    wrksheetcheckbox.type = "checkbox";
    wrksheetcheckbox.name = arrworksheets[i];
    wrksheetcheckbox.value = arrworksheets[i];
    wrksheetcheckbox.id = arrworksheets[i];

    var wrksheetlabel = document.createElement("label");
    wrksheetlabel.htmlFor = arrworksheets[i];
    wrksheetlabel.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arrworksheets[i]));

    var brk = document.createElement("br");

    td.appendChild(wrksheetcheckbox);
    td.appendChild(wrksheetlabel);
    tr.appendChild(td);
    table.appendChild(tr);

    table.rows[i+1].insertCell(1);
}
```

insertCell is working in HTML but not working in Sharepoint. Am I missing something. The row has already been created though.

I am trying to insert a cell in the 2nd column and then add data to it.

Comment: You already have the `tr` object. Have you tried applying `insertCell` into that?

Comment: I tried tr.insertCell it didnt work. After the loop i used table.rows.length to get the number of rows. I am getting 1 (because i have one row header) even if the output should be greater than one. Are the rows not getting created?

Comment: I am not sure.. you can probably use the browser developer tools and debug the javascript

Answer (score 0):

When you create rows in for loop, you get a row table.rows[i+1] which doesn't exists yet, that caused the error.

Here is my test code for your reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var table = document.getElementById("WrksheetTable");
        //test data
        var arrworksheets = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
        for (i = 0; i < arrworksheets.length; i++) {
            var tr = document.createElement("tr");
            tr.id = "tr" + i;
            var td = document.createElement("td");
            td.id = "td" + i;
            var wrksheetcheckbox = document.createElement("input");
            wrksheetcheckbox.type = "checkbox";
            wrksheetcheckbox.name = arrworksheets[i];
            wrksheetcheckbox.value = arrworksheets[i];
            wrksheetcheckbox.id = arrworksheets[i];

            var wrksheetlabel = document.createElement("label");
            wrksheetlabel.htmlFor = arrworksheets[i];
            wrksheetlabel.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arrworksheets[i]));

            var brk = document.createElement("br");

            td.appendChild(wrksheetcheckbox);
            td.appendChild(wrksheetlabel);
            tr.appendChild(td);
            table.appendChild(tr);

            var x = table.rows[i].insertCell(1);
            x.innerHTML = "New cell";
        }
    }
</script>
```

update:
The sample result:
[image]

Comment: I have a question. In this test case did it add 3 cells with New Cell as the value?

Comment: Add the result above.